# Why cant i download tor? It stops half way through and says error

Tags: tor-install

[image]

Every time I try to download Tor, an error message pops up.

Comment: It looks like you may be out of disk space.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the partition you're installing tor into isn't full.
2. Also make sure that you have administrative access or you've permission to write files into that partition.